# How to write a letter to work at an university?

Tags: research-process, job-search, application-cover-letter, russia

I'm writing a speculative letter to work at university in Siberia.

My real motivation is that I'm slowly changing my mind. After graduation I immediately started working as engineer because I thought I wanted to build things. I never stopped studying and if anything I studied more while working than before. I just started working in a R&D lab so I could reconcile all the time spent studying with actual work. Still I'm not convinced and I'm writing a letter to find a contact in an university I like with the hope that I could *somehow* be hired.

The problem is that my academic cv is incredibly poor. This is what I have in a nutshell

- Master degree with full grades
- One publication in prestigious journal based on master thesis
- 3 years of relevant work in the field

Soon I will have a book published. It's a technical book but it's not academic, not sure if it counts.

In the letter I'm writing I tried to explain why the technology I'm researching is important and have practical applications worldwide. I listed my publication saying that it contains *some* results of my research. Finally I specified that I'm working in a R&D lab and I'm developing expertise on the topic.

In the letter I ask if the university have done some research with this technology and I ask for a contact.

When I started writing I was convinced to do something useful but reading the letter to myself, I imagined to be a professor and I would be puzzled and chances are I would ignore the email.

How can I write a letter with some chances to find job in this university? Is it possible that a professor could be interested in a collaboration with me? How to best elicit interest supposing my research field is of genuine and immediate importance? What is the most probable position I could aspire to?

Comment: If you want an academic career, you have to go the long slog. Looks like you could try for a PhD, then a postdoc or two, then a more junior professorship.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs thanks, that is clear to me, there are equivalents in Europe. In Russia there is a slightly different system. With less formalities. That's what my question is about.

Comment: Are you writing a letter or an email? If you're worried about someone ignoring your communication, a physical letter might be better. Better still, find a professor who is already working in the same area as you; if they're already interested in the technology they won't need convincing of its importance.

Comment: @NatalieHogg thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely opt for the letter.